# How to make Tridion folder structure configurable in custom GUI Extension (to hide retired schema)?

Tags: web8.5, gui-extensions, javascript

I have a requirement to hide schema's not in use.
In order to do that, my custom GUI extension is working fine. However, I am facing challenges in making schema list configurable to pick from Tridion folder structure.
Currently, I am passing Schema list in an array.

I would need suggestion,to make it configurable.

Below is my code snippet:

[image]

Comment: The alternative approach is to move schemas not in use to the separate folder and revoke read access on this folder for the most users (only admins will be able get to them). CM will filter such schemas out from the list of available schemas.

Comment: @AntonM - Thank you for the input. However, additionally the requirement is to allow  author to edit the existing components based on schema's not in use. So, In this alternative approach this scenario will not work.

Comment: @MohanKushwaha, Is the intend to retire the schemas that are not in use? Just curious as to see why you want to hide them using a UI extension.

Comment: @Shiva -  Scenario is that business do not want to allow editors to create new components based upon retired schema's. Also, existing components are still in use and editing is allowed for those components.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a folder, could retired schemas not have their title/description updated with a token like "[Retired]" that you can then detect and remove if you subsequent methods?

Comment: Thank you. I have not tried this option, will check on this.

Comment: +1. I'd even recommend starting with this change then revisiting the need to hide Schemas from the drop-down.

Answer (score 0):

@Mohan - You can start using webdav folder path and all retired schema can be maintained in that folder. and that webdav path also can be maintained using app.config file.

Comment: I am not getting the access to webdav path in javascript code i have shared. However, Yes I have used webdav path for other scenarios like restricting copy paste of components based upon retired schema in my event system code.